# How to get a value from a TableView?

Tags: java, javafx

**How do I get a value form a TableView in a determined preferred Row and Column?**

::getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() not working at all.

[This is my TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3mYU.png)

From this table, how do I get "Carlos Araujo" ID as a String...

Comment: post **code** not pictures if you want help with code, and definitely do not post pictures of code

Comment: Jarrod Roberson, the Question "How fetch a Cell value from a column in TableView javafx? " does not provide a straight answer for my question. I wanna get the value form a cell and convert it into a string value.

Answer (score 1):

If your line is an object :

```
Object obj = table.getItems().get(table.getFocusModel().getFocusedIndex());
```

You get your object can take any information on it.

Comment: Note that the question mentions the selected item from a selection model, which may not be the same as a focused item from the focus model.

Comment: In the screenshot it selects the entire line I thought that was what he wanted.

Comment: Why do I get this result: youclubfx.FuncDataFactory@11191296 ...? Which is "MyProjectName.MyConstractorClassName@11191296.